# Отрисовка крестика и нолика через Shapes

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Подскажите, как правильно отрисовать самостоятельно фигуры в ячейках?

Поле представляет Grid заполненное кнопками, при клику по кнопке происходит изменение enum у привязанного объекта с empty на cross или zero.

Разметка поля выглядит так:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding BattleField}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ScrollViewer.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level2">
                <Button Height="40" Width="50" Click="Button_Click">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level1">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level2}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ScrollViewer.Resources>
        <ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level1}"></ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Соответственно так обрабатывается Click по кнопке:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Source is Button)
        {
            var content = (e.Source as Button).DataContext;
            if (content is Field)
            {
                var cell = (content as Field);
                if (cell.FieldType == CellType.Empty)
                {
                    cell.FieldType = ViewModel.BattleField.GetNewStep();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Хотелось бы сделать вместо привязки текста у кнопки

```
                <Button Height="40" Width="50" Click="Button_Click">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                </Button>
```

Реализовать анимированную отрисовку крестика и нолика через триггер с привязкой к `cell.FieldType`

Но не понимаю, как привязаться к значению данного свойства и отрисовать соответствующую фигуру в контенте кнопки.

Answer (score 0):

В общем с enum так и не разобрался как сделать, но проблему решил путем реализация классов на каждый enum и привязку datatemplate на каждый из классов.

Если есть более элегантное решение, было бы здорово услышать.